# ReactJS hover/mouseover effect for one list item instead of all list items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hover, components

I am a React novice, so this might seem really simple, or maybe it isn't, I'm not sure. I'm building a basic to-do list. I want a mouseover effect on list items to pop up "delete this" text. But for my code so far, when I mouseover a list item, "delete this" pops up for all list items instead of just the one.

When I tried solving this by creating a new component for individual list items, that didn't seem to work. Any help is much appreciated!

```
class ToDosContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      heading: 'Something You Need To Do?',
      todos: [
        'wake up',
        'brush your teeth'
      ],
    }

    this.addToDo = this.addToDo.bind(this)
  }

  addToDo(todo) {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      todos: state.todos.concat([todo])
    }))
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>To Do List</h1>
        <h3>{this.state.heading}</h3>
        <AddToDo addNew={this.addToDo} />
        <ShowList tasks={this.state.todos} />
      </div>  
    )
  }
}

class AddToDo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      newToDo: ''
    }

    this.updateNewToDo = this.updateNewToDo.bind(this)
    this.handleAddToDo = this.handleAddToDo.bind(this)

  }

  //I think I can delete this part
  updateNewToDo(e) {
    this.setState({
      newToDo: e.target.value
    })
  }
 //

  handleAddToDo() {
    this.props.addNew(this.state.newToDo)
    this.setState({
      newToDo: ''
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.newToDo}
          onChange={this.updateNewToDo}
         />
        <button onClick={this.handleAddToDo}> Add To Do </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class ShowList extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      newToDo: ''
    }
  }

  onMouseOver(e) { 
    this.setState({
      text: 'delete me'
    })
    console.log('hey')
  }

  onMouseOut(e) { 
     this.setState({
      text: ''
    })
     console.log('hey hey')

  }

  render() {
   const { text } = this.state;
   return (
    <div>
       <h4>To Do's</h4>
       <ul>
          {this.props.tasks.map((todo) => {
            return <li onMouseEnter={this.onMouseOver.bind(this)} onMouseLeave={this.onMouseOut.bind(this)}> {todo} {text}</li>
          })}
       </ul>
    </div>
   ) 
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ToDosContainer />, document.getElementById('helloworld'));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would make a Task component. You don't want to set the state of the text in the `ListView` component, because then `this.state.text` is shared by each task in the map. Each task should be aware of its own hover, and not the hover of the other children.

```
class Task extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: ""
  };
  onMouseOver(e) {
    this.setState({
      text: "delete me"
    });
  }

  onMouseOut(e) {
    this.setState({
      text: ""
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <li
        onMouseEnter={this.onMouseOver.bind(this)}
        onMouseLeave={this.onMouseOut.bind(this)}
      >
        {this.props.todo} {this.state.text}
      </li>
    );
  }
}


class ShowList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      newToDo: ""
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { text } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>To Do's</h4>
        <ul>
          {this.props.tasks.map(todo => {
            return <Task todo={todo} />;
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Very helpful as I try to figure out React.

Comment: Thanks again for your help last week. For the past week I've been trying to figure out how to actually go ahead and delete a list item with a click, in React. Here's what I have thus far and nothing's worked. I suspect something goes into line 95: https://codepen.io/bfoley650/pen/mKPgdE?editors=0011

Comment: @bfoley_teamug I love your hustle, nice work! So, again, you're really close. In the same way that you pass the addTask handler from the TodosContainer to the AddTodo component, you have to pass the removeTask from the TodosContainer to the ShowList component. However, once there, you have to pass one level further, from the ShowList component, to the Task itself. Once binded in the constructor, your action can be passed down to as many children as you want, and will be able to modify the parent's state. Here's the codepen with the changes:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RJRRdP?editors=0011

Comment: Thanks so much, really appreciate it

Comment: Could you fill me in on what's going on with this piece of code on line 145: key={`todo-${key}-${todo}`} .  Thank you again very much for helping me out!

Comment: Sure thing. So, when you are iterating over an array, it is good practice to uniquely identify each list item in the map, or row. However, using just the index of the array isn't very helpful, because that key is not very unique, and if you sort the array, then the keys will stay the same. So this is a way of giving an extra unique and specific identifier to the list item. If you remove it, this should probably still work fine, it's just a best practice thing that can *sometimes* bite. React will warn you if you exclude a unique key from mapped elements.